# Delete property in two separate objects without redundant delete statements

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to delete properties in two unrelated objects. is there any way to avoid doing this?

```
delete a.prop
delete b.prop
```

I tried:

```
delete a.prop && b.prop
```

and

```
delete a.prop,b.prop
```

but in both cases, b.prop remained intact. is there anyway to avoid these redundant delete statements (without writing a function for it)? why doesn't the `&&` operator work?

Comment: Yes... This is how it should work.. what is the question ?

Comment: Syntax for `delete operator` is `"delete expression"` and _expression should evaluate to a property reference_ so `delete a.prop,b.prop` will not help as this is not a valid syntax..

Comment: what's up with the downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not redundant. They're concise, and clear about what they're doing. The delete operator deletes a single property - any "creative" code you come up with that means you only have to write `delete` once will end up looking a lot worse, and be a lot longer than the 6 characters of `delete`.

> why doesn't the `&&` operator work?

Because the `delete` operator has a [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `&&`, and takes a single expression, meaning that:

```
delete a.prop && b.prop
```

Is the same as

```
(delete a.prop) && b.prop
```

IE the delete happens first, with the result of that being the first operand to `&&`.

Similarly for using `,`, the `delete` is only operating on the expression to the left of the comma.

Comment: _Operator precedence_ reference is really helpful...Thanks..+1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

The delete operator only accepts one property. Your code isn't redundant.

Comment: Please see [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Answer (score 0):

One delete per object isn't redundant:

> The delete operator removes a property from an object.

Source: [Mozilla MDN,Delete Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Also you can see how delete operator works step by step  [ECMAScript , 11.4.1 The delete Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.1)

Comment: `ECMAScript` reference did not say about how does it work.. Can you clarify ?

Comment: Why not, from ECMAScript reference: "1.Let ref be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression. 2......."

Comment: Does that mean _"works step by step"_ ? I doubt.. Do clarify if possible.. Thanks :)